# Expect never checks for match

Tags: linux, expect

I have a simple test script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh username@server.net ls
ssh username@server.net ls
exit 0
```

I also have an Expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set timeout -1
spawn ./test.sh
expect -exact "username@server.net's password: "
send -- "mypassword\r"
expect eof
```

This works fine on the first call to `ssh`, but of course does not fill the second password prompt. Seemingly the solution is something like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set timeout -1
spawn ./test.sh
expect {
      "username@server.net's password: " {
            send -- "mypassword\r"
            exp_continue
      }
}
expect eof
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It just shows me the password prompt and doesn't fill it, not even the first time.

The working version outputs the following when I call it with `expect -d`:

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = test.exp
set argc 0
set argv0 "test.exp"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file test.exp
spawn ./test.sh
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {23031}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp8) match exact string "username@server.net's password: "? no
username@server.net's password:
expect: does "username@server.net's password: " (spawn_id exp8) match exact string "username@server.net's password: "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "username@server.net's password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp8"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "username@server.net's password: "
send: sending "mypassword\r" to { exp8 }
```

The non-working version is character-for-character identical through `spawn: returns {...}` (although it's a different number, of course). But then it just skips to the password prompt without doing any checks for a match, and stays there:

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = test.exp
set argc 0
set argv0 "test.exp"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file test.exp
spawn ./test.sh
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {85647}
username@server.net's password:
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using a loop to do this because, in my real script, it's unknown how many times the password prompt will need to be filled. I'm not using SSH keys because the server admin has disabled that.)

Comment: Would be helpful to see the debug output for the non-working version.

Comment: Of course, this would not be a problem if you switched to SSH keys, and you didn't have to enter a password at all. `ssh-keygen` then `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: `diff` shows that non-working version's output is character-for-character the same, up until the number in the line `spawn: returns {...}`. As I said, it then differs in that it skips the first `expect:` line, then shows the password prompt and stops there. Also, as I mentioned, I can't use SSH keys.

Comment: please post the `expect -d` output for the non-working version.

Comment: I've now added the output of `expect -d` for the non-working version.

Comment: Small note, you're using `expect -exact` in your first example but not in your second. This won't affect your issue, but could lead to unexpected behavior later.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is, in the expect command with just one branch and exp_continue, is that there's no "break" condition. Try this:

```
expect {
      " password: " {
            send -- "mypassword\r"
            exp_continue
      }
      eof
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, unfortunately.